During a POST call to a mvc springboot application want to force a boolean parameter to fault
Having a MVC pattern Sprinboot application we want the user to send a POST call to register a new PuntoDiInteresse document into a MongoDB collection. The verificato  field is entitled to show if the point has been validated by a Curatore so when we create a new one that field must be on false until the Curatore proceed to validate it.
Model:
package it.unicam.cs.LocalDevelopmentPlatform.luoghi;

import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import java.util.Objects;

@Document(collection = "PuntoDiInteresse")
public class PuntoDiInteresse {
    @Id
    private int _id;

    private Coordinata coordinata;
    private String nome;
    private TipologiaPunto tipologia;
    private boolean verificato;
    private boolean segnalato;
    private String descrizione;
    private String motivoSegnalazione;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof PuntoDiInteresse that)) return false;
        return verificato == that.verificato && segnalato == that.segnalato && Objects.equals(coordinata, that.coordinata)
                && Objects.equals(nome, that.nome) && tipologia == that.tipologia && Objects.equals(descrizione, that.descrizione)
                && Objects.equals(motivoSegnalazione, that.motivoSegnalazione);
    }

    public PuntoDiInteresse(Coordinata coordinata, String nome, TipologiaPunto tipologia, String descrizione) {
        //TODO bisogna vedere come mai il deserializzatore bypassi totalmente questo costruttore quando va a creare un'istanza
        // e quindi si può fare injection e forzare il campo a true del verificato e del segnalato.
        this.coordinata = coordinata;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.tipologia = tipologia;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.setMotivoSegnalazione(null);
        this.setVerificato(false);
        this.setSegnalato(false);
        this._id = this.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Math.abs(Objects.hash(coordinata, nome, tipologia, descrizione));
    }

    public int get_id() {
        return _id;
    }

    public void setSegnalato(boolean segnalato) {
        this.segnalato = segnalato;
    }

    public void setVerificato(boolean verificato) {
        this.verificato = verificato;
    }

    public Coordinata getCoordinata() {
        return coordinata;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public TipologiaPunto getTipologia() {
        return tipologia;
    }

    public boolean isVerificato() {return verificato; }

    public void verifica(){ this.verificato = true; }

    public boolean isSegnalato() {return segnalato; }

    public void segnala(){ this.segnalato= true; }

    public String getDescrizione() {
        return descrizione;
    }

    public String getMotivoSegnalazione() {
        return motivoSegnalazione;
    }

    public void setMotivoSegnalazione(String motivoSegnalazione) {
        this.motivoSegnalazione = motivoSegnalazione;
    }
}

Repository:
package it.unicam.cs.LocalDevelopmentPlatform.repository;

import it.unicam.cs.LocalDevelopmentPlatform.luoghi.PuntoDiInteresse;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface PuntoDiInteresseRepo extends MongoRepository<PuntoDiInteresse, java.lang.Integer> {

    @Query("{ '_id' : ?0 }")
    PuntoDiInteresse findById(int id);

    @Query("{verificato : true}")
    @Override
    List<PuntoDiInteresse> findAll();

    @Query("{verificato : false}")
    List<PuntoDiInteresse> findAllFalse();

}

Controller:
package it.unicam.cs.LocalDevelopmentPlatform.controller;

import it.unicam.cs.LocalDevelopmentPlatform.luoghi.Itinerario;
import it.unicam.cs.LocalDevelopmentPlatform.service.PuntoInteresseService;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import it.unicam.cs.LocalDevelopmentPlatform.luoghi.PuntoDiInteresse;

import it.unicam.cs.LocalDevelopmentPlatform.service.ItinerarioService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("contributor")
public class ContributorController extends TuristaController {

    public ContributorController(PuntoInteresseService puntoInteresseService, ItinerarioService itinerarioService) {
        super(puntoInteresseService, itinerarioService);
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/caricaPunto")
    public void caricaPunto(@RequestBody PuntoDiInteresse puntoDiInteresse) {
        puntoInteresseService.savePunto(puntoDiInteresse);
    }

    @PostMapping("/caricaItinerario")
    public void caricaItinerario(@RequestBody Itinerario itinerario){itinerarioService.saveItinerario(itinerario);}
}

Service:
package it.unicam.cs.LocalDevelopmentPlatform.service;

import it.unicam.cs.LocalDevelopmentPlatform.luoghi.PuntoDiInteresse;
import it.unicam.cs.LocalDevelopmentPlatform.repository.PuntoDiInteresseRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class PuntoInteresseService {


    private final PuntoDiInteresseRepo puntoDiInteresseRepo;

    @Autowired
    public PuntoInteresseService(PuntoDiInteresseRepo puntoDiInteresseRepo) {
        this.puntoDiInteresseRepo = puntoDiInteresseRepo;
    }

    public List<PuntoDiInteresse> getAllPunti() {
        return puntoDiInteresseRepo.findAll();
    }

    public List<PuntoDiInteresse> getAllPuntiById(List<Integer> punti){return puntoDiInteresseRepo.findAllById(punti);}

    public PuntoDiInteresse getPuntoByID(int id) {
        return puntoDiInteresseRepo.findById(id);
    }

    public void savePunto(PuntoDiInteresse puntoDiInteresse) {
        puntoDiInteresseRepo.save(puntoDiInteresse);
    }

    public void deletePunto(int id){puntoDiInteresseRepo.deleteById(id);}

    public List<PuntoDiInteresse> getAllNotVerified() {
        return puntoDiInteresseRepo.findAllFalse();
    }

    public void verificaPunto(int id) {
        PuntoDiInteresse daVer = puntoDiInteresseRepo.findById(id);
        daVer.verifica();
        puntoDiInteresseRepo.deleteById(id);
        puntoDiInteresseRepo.save(daVer);
    }
}

POSTMAN request:
{
    "coordinata": {
        "latitudine": "{{randomLat}}",
        "longitudine": "{{randomLong}}"
    },
    "nome": "Name",
    "tipologia": "{{randomTipologia}}",
    "verificato": "true",    
    "descrizione": "Description"
}

We tried to put some constraint on the constructor using default parameter, using the set function and even rewrite a JSON deserializer but the program continues to let the user to create a new document forcing the field to true.

If you don't want the user to provide a value for verificato, then don't use a class which has that field in caricaPunto.
